# System.Diagnostics.Process: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, command-line

I have the following code:

```
        // Creating procesStartInfo obj
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo
            = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        // Do not create the black window.
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        //Window state hidden .. so black windows will come inbetween
        procStartInfo.WindowStyle
            = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        // Creating Process obj to run the net time cmd
        System.Diagnostics.Process p;
        string output;
        p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "w32tm";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        p.StartInfo.Arguments = " /resync /computer:xxxxx977";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();

        output = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine().ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(output);
```

When I execute this code, I am getting an error message:

> The following error occurred : The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E).

If I run remotely or locally the command `w32tm /resync /computer:xxxxx977`, it works fine. Why do I get this error when starting a process with code, but not from the command-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
```

You didn't specify, where to find "w32tm", so maybe the file could not be found. I think you have to provide the full path and the extension of it, or otherwise UseShellExecute.

BTW: Some properties are set twice in your code. ;-)

Comment: If is UserShellExecute then i cant redirect the standard output. What can i do for that??

Comment: Then try to specify the full path and filename with extension. e.g. "C:\Windows\System32\W32tm.exe"

Comment: Hi fischermaen, I tried. But i couldn't achieve the time resync thru c# code. Can you please help me in this more

Comment: @Yes-kaY: I don't exactly understand, what you mean. It works now, but you want to know when the process is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DependencyWalker` tool to find out which modules are missing and cannot be found along the search PATH. It might help to set `UseShellExecute` to true. What was your reasoning to set it to false?